# How to restrict program to connect only to a whitelist of hosts?

Tags: windows, proxy, firewall, hosts, hostname

I want to restrict some program to be allowed to connect only to a whitelist of hosts.

What it the simplest way to achieve this?

OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

[Per this How-To Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/) you can do this in Windows Firewall by using a Custom Rule Outbound Rule and choosing the Scope option.

1) Open Windows Firewall and select the Advanced settings.

[image: Windows Firewall Advanced Settings]

2) Create a new Outbound Rule.

[image: Windows Firewall New Outbound Rule]

3) In the wizard, choose Custom Rule. Fill out the information regarding the program you wish to block and any necessary port data.

[image: Windows Firewall Custom Rule]

4) Under the Scope options, whitelist any IP addresses you wish then finish the rule as normal (allow the connection).

[image: Windows Firewall Scope Settings]

Comment: Thank you, but it only restricts to IPs, and I needed to restrict to domains (the application has an [embedded browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework). I tried a (questionable) program based on [Titanium Web Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy) and it did the job, kind of.